# Definition of a faithful state

Tags: functional-analysis

I am writing my thesis, and have to give a definition of what it means for a state on an algebra to be faithful. My memory is failing me, and i am unable to find an answer to such a simple question. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=state+on+an+algebra+to+be+faithful&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS791US791&oq=state+on+an+algebra+to+be+faithful&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns this [pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311438) first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of $C^*$-algebras, a **state** is a norm-one linear functional $\varphi:A\to\mathbb C$ on a $C^*$-algebra $A$ such that $\varphi(x^*x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in A$.  We say the state $\varphi$ is **faithful** if $\varphi(x^*x)=0$ implies $x=0$.

For an example, consider the $C^*$-algebra $C([0,1])$, and let $\varphi:C([0,1])\to\mathbb C$ be given by $\varphi(f)=\int f\ dm$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.  Certainly $\varphi$ has norm-one.  If $f\in C([0,1])$, then 
$$\varphi(f^*f)=\int|f|^2dm\geq 0$$
so $\varphi$ is a state.  Moreover, it is faithful:  if $f\in C([0,1])$ and  $\int|f|^2dm=0$, then $f=0$.